# Change Terminal Theme for Developing

Tags: terminal, imac, macos, themes

I just got an iMac and wanted to change the default terminal to, what i believe, is a theme.

I saw it a while ago and i'm not finding it.

Screenshot below.

[image]

You can find a video from Yeoman using it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBt2g9ekiug)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest I've found is the [Steeef theme](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/steeef.zsh-theme) for [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh). It seems very close, except the font/background is different (however that is set externally in Terminal settings).

[image]

To install this:

1. Install Homebrew and zsh, then set zsh as default shell.

   ```
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
   brew install zsh
   chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh
   ```
2. Restart Terminal.
3. Install oh-my-zsh.

   ```
   curl -L https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh | sh
   ```
4. Edit `ZSH_THEME` in `~/.zshrc` to be `steeef`.

   [image]
5. Restart Terminal.

Comment: I think the screenshot is pretty similar. Can you help me installing it ? I'm pretty new to mac's :)

Comment: @TheMiniJohn I've edited my answer :)

Comment: Hey i finished Step 3, but i can't find ~/.zshrc. How can i find and open this file ?

Comment: @TheMiniJohn It's a hidden file in the root of your home directory. If you have TextMate (with CLI) installed, you can run `mate ~/.zshrc`. Alternatively, you can edit it in Terminal with nano using `nano ~/.zshrc`. If you want to unhide the file to show it in Finder (to edit it with TextEdit etc) run `chflags nohidden ~/.zshrc`.